# Event_New API timezone - does it accept Olson tz values?

Tags: timezone, eventbrite

Does anyone know if this API will accept Olson tz labels like "America/Los_Angeles" for the timezone field?

I'm using this API: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_new/

Where it says for timezone:

```
The event time zone in relation to GMT (e.g., “GMT+01″, “GMT+02″, “GMT-01″).
```

I know from other community discussion that this will also accept values like "US/Pacific".

I also took a look at the select dropdown in the manual event entry form, and the values appear to be Olson tz labels. I just want to know if anyone can confirm this. I'll confirm it myself once I get the event post working through the API, but would love to save time by knowing ahead of time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Olson tz labels are allowed on input, and are now the default output format for that field.

The previous timezone input values ('GMT+8', 'US/Pacific', 'PT', etc.) are still allowed, and are now automatically remapped to their Olson-compatible equivalent ('America/Los Angeles') on input.

Comment: Thank you! I'll mark this as the answer just as soon as our tests confirm. Not that I seriously doubt you.

Comment: Great! 
Please let me know if you spot any inconsistencies that need to be fixed.