# Event_New API timezone - Supported Timezone List

Tags: timezone, eventbrite

**Where is the supported timezone list?**

When we call Event_New with a timezone 'America/Boise' we receive an error:

```
Invalid time zone.  Please consult our list of supported timezones.
```

I found this link: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/timezones/.

On it, I found 'America/Boise' listed (not working), and we know that 'Pacific/Honolulu' is working, but is not on this list. **I wonder if there is a definitive list somewhere?**

### More Info

We got our timezone list from http://www.geonames.org: (http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/timeZones.txt)

We can make adjustments to our conversion script to account for outliers, but it would be good to know what is acceptable and what is not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Any Olson timezone label should be a valid input on Eventbrite's API.  This sounds like a bug.

I've filed a bug report with Eventbrite for this issue.  I'll update here when it's resolved.

Comment: Ok. Just FYI, two other timezones that are not working are 'America/Indiana/Indianapolis' andn 'America/Kentucky/Louisville'

Comment: Thanks. I'll add those to the bug report

Comment: I didn't have any problem with 'America/Kentucky/Louisville'.  'America/Fort_Wayne' may work as a substitute for 'America/Indiana/Indianapolis' while Eventbrite looks into this.

Comment: Thanks. It's curious. I just tried 'America/Kentucky/Louisville' again, and it is still throwing the same error. I wonder if there is some other validation going on.

Comment: It seems this bug is still present. But now it seems inputs in form of GMT-X are invalid too, so there doesn't seem to be an easy or effective workaround to this issue any more. Based on test I ran, timezone input values of `'Etc/GMT-4'`, based on the mapping linked above, along with `'GMT-4'`, `'GMT-04'`, and `'America/Moncton'` do not work. `America/Halifax` works but we get the Olson value based on location, and it is difficult to somehow map it to an "equivalent" Olson value that works...

Answer (score 0):

Comment to Ryan's answer (I'm not at 50 yet and can't comment). Seems 'America/Moncton' is not supported as well?

Request data:

```
{ title: 'geofreddy',
  start_date: '2013-08-10 09:00:00',
  end_date: '2013-08-17 17:00:00',
  timezone: 'America/Moncton',
  venue_id: <id of my venue> }
```

API response:

```
{ error_type: 'Timezone error',
  error_message: 'Invalid time zone.  Please consult our list of supported timezones.' }
```

Seeing this question:

[Event_New API timezone - does it accept Olson tz values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180293/event-new-api-timezone-does-it-accept-olson-tz-values)

I am able to work around by passing the timezone as GMT offset (ie. GMT-4).